# Rails + Capybara: Selecting select option using HTML class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My select looks like this:

```
    <select id="product_products_colors_attributes_0_variants_attributes_1401459162565_size_id" class="size_select" name="product[products_colors_attributes][0][variants_attributes][1401459162565][size_id]">
        <option value="1">XS</option>
        <option value="2">S</option>
        <option value="3">M</option>
        <option value="4">L</option>
        <option value="5">XL</option>
        <option value="6">One Size</option>
    </select>
```

The thing is that the `1401459162565` part is random (comes from the nested_form gem). How would I select `M` from this select dropdown using the class (or ID or any way that works with the random number)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly new to Capybara, but as I understand it, you can select for embedded elements (by class) like this:

```
  within('.select_box') do
    click_on "Option"
  end
```

There is also the select method:

```
select('Option', :from => 'Select Box')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
within("#product_products_colors_attributes_0_variants_attributes") do
   #write your spec here
end
```

AFAIK query isn't exact by default, so it should find an element which has a contains substring specified as param to `within`.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I just went with this... nothing us worked. This only works because there is only one select dropdown in my div:

```
within(new_variant_div) do
  page.all(:css, "option")[-1].click
end
```